# How to set the latest TFS repo changeset number into a variable in windows batch file

Tags: shell, batch-file, tfs, command-line

I am getting the latest changes of my project from TFS and running static code analysis. I would like to save the latest changeset with the results. I want to use it in a windows batch file.

Here is how I get the latest revision:

```
"%VSINSTALLDIR%Common7\IDE\TF.exe" get $/%ProjectName% /recursive
```

I check the latest changeset number with:

```
"%VSINSTALLDIR%Common7\IDE\TF.exe" localversions %ProjectName%
```

Output of above command is like following:

```
C:\Projects\VeriPark:
ProjectName;C23456

1 item(s)
```

I would like to set version variable to latest changeset number. (version=23456 according to above output). I don't prefer to save out put to a temporary file if possible. Even if I save it to version.txt file I couldn't get the second line.

When the output in a file, I can read it with a for statement. However I couldn't get the second line. After getting the second line I could parse the version number like following:

```
SET Version=%Line:~14,5%
```

I need help with two issues:

1. How to get output of a command (second localversion command) in batch file without using temporary file?
2. How to parse multi line variable to get requested line (getting second line, or a line starts with project name)?

Thank you in advance

Comment: it is going to be difficult for me to test this, but you can run a loop, I will post an answer you have to test it for me though.

Comment: Thank you @GerhardBarnard for looking into it. I have found answer to my first question. Counted lines and output them  I could get first and last line but not the middle one. I am looking into delims and token for the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this from cmdline:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,* delims=;" %i in ('"%VSINSTALLDIR%Common7\IDE\TF.exe" localversions %ProjectName%') do echo %j
```

if you want to create a batch file, then:

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,* delims=;" %%i in ('"%VSINSTALLDIR%Common7\IDE\TF.exe" localversions %ProjectName%') do echo %%j
```

To set it as a permanent environment variable, you can look at `setx` but be careful not to use an existing system or user environment variable. That should be something like:

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,* delims=;" %%i in ('"%VSINSTALLDIR%Common7\IDE\TF.exe" localversions %ProjectName%') do setx SOMEVAR %%j
```

Finally, If it does not do what is expected, we skip 1, then exit the loop once we got the second row (which is technically now the 1st):

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,* delims=;" %%i in ('"%VSINSTALLDIR%Common7\IDE\TF.exe" localversions %ProjectName%') do setx SOMEVAR %%j & goto :EOF
```

In summary:

1. Output of a command can be looped over without saving to a temporary file.
2. Following will get the exact line into a variable.

   ```
   for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%G in ('"%VSINSTALLDIR%Common7\IDE\TF.exe" localversions %ProjectName%') do if %%G equ 3 set Line=%%H
   SET Version=%Line:~11,5%
   ECHO %Version%
   ```

This code will read the 3rd line and set it to Line variable which I parsed version number from. Above lines will display get version number from TFS.

Comment: Thank you @GerhardBernard. I have first tried a similar version to this but I could not get the exact line I wanted. As you answered, the delims part was missing. I will edit your answer to give more information. Please feel free to edit it again.

Comment: Just check the final changes, then feel free to edit, I will ammend where needed.

Comment: Added the final working code to your answer and set as accepted answer.